# Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Node.prototype) fails

Tags: javascript, webview

I am logging my errors on a web page that's running javascript, and I see that the following code:

```
JSON.stringify(
      Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Node.prototype)
    );
```

fails with:

```
undefined is not a function
```

What could be the explanation for that? I am under the assumption this happens when the page was loaded not on a normal browser but by using WebView.

I opened an Android Emulator and verified this page on a normal browser and using a WebView Test app - it worked fine.

What else can I do to debug it? This error is raised quite often.

**Edit**

I added further logging and I checked the following:

```
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Node.prototype, "childNodes");
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Node.prototype, "parentNode");
Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Node.prototype, "hasChildNodes");
```

And only for `hasChildNodes` a value is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would appear that on some of the browser/webview brands or versions your code runs on, either `JSON.stringify` or (more likely) `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors` is not defined (the former was added in ES5, the latter much more recently in ES2017).

> What else can I do to debug it?

Add tests and log the user agent string:

```
if (!JSON.stringify) {
    /* ...log that `JSON.stringify` isn't supported, w/`navigator.userAgent`...*/
} else if (!Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors) {
    /* ...log that `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors` isn't supported, w/`navigator.userAgent`...*/
} else {
    /* ...log `JSON.stringify(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptors(Node.prototype))` ... */
}
```

---

In a comment you've asked:

> So do you know of a way in which I could get the getter function `childNodes` of the `Node.prototype` in whichever browser? In all my tests (mobile emulators and browsers) it is always an "own" property of the `Node.prototype`.

If you're seeing `undefined` for `Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(Node.prototype, "childNodes")` in some unusual implementation, you may have to loop using `Object.getPrototypeOf` to find where it is in the inheritance chain:

```
function getDescriptor(obj, name) {
    let descr;
    while (obj && !(descr = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj, name))) {
        obj = Object.getPrototypeOf(obj);
    }
    return descr;
}
```

Then you'd use `const childNodesDescriptor = getDescriptor(Node.prototype, "childNodes");` or similar.

But beware that host-provided objects like `Node.prototype` are also allowed to break some (but not all) rules. You may have to allow for the possibility there are implementations where you just can't get that getter.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I added further logging - I updated my question.
Do you have an explanation why  Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor works only for one property ("hasChildNodes") out of three?

Comment: @Yaron - Presumably the other two aren't *own* properties, they're inherited ones.

Comment: So do you know of a way in which I could get the getter function ```childNodes``` of the ```Node.prototype``` in whichever browser? In all my tests (mobile emulators and browsers) it is always an "own" property of the ```Node.prototype```.

Comment: @Yaron - I've updated the answer to answer that comment. We're getting pretty far afield from the original question, though... :-)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Should just edit ```obj.getPrototypeOf(obj)``` to ```Object.getPrototypeOf(obj)``` :)

Comment: @Yaron - Oops! Fixed. You can directly fix things like that in future (in cases like this where it was an obvious typo). Happy coding!